# Manipulate function to generate outliers

Tags: manipulate

How to use `Manipulate[]` to make a point move vertically and become an outlier? Here I am trying to make $50$-th point move vertically.I have tried as below:

```
n = 100;
data3 = Table[{t, t^2 + 0.4 RandomReal[]}, {t, 0.0, 10.0, 10/n}];
Print [data3];
point = Part[data3, 50];
Manipulate[ListPlot[data3], {data3[[1]], 0.0, 10}];
```

Comment: `Manipulate[ListPlot[ReplacePart[data3, {50, 2} -> i]], {i, 0.0, 100}]` Is that what you want?

Comment: n = 100;
data3 = Table[{t, t^2 + 0.4 RandomReal[]}, {t, 0.0, 10.0, 10/n}];
Print [data3];
point = Part[data3, 50];
Manipulate[ListPlot[ReplacePart[data3, {50, 2} -> i]], {i, 0.0, 100}];

may be ,.....but its not printing anything....the plot etc

Comment: You need to get rid of the `;` after your manipulate, it's suppressing the output.

Comment: Yes...It works..Thank you. :D

Comment: hi N.J.Evans......can you help me with this question...an extension to current one.http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109151/calling-multiple-functions-in-manipulate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @N.J.Evans above:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[ReplacePart[data3, {50, 2} -> i]], {i, 0.0, 100}]
```

Comment: Consider acknowledging in this answer the comment by @N.J.Evans.

Comment: Yes...Thank you N.J.Evans for the answer.. and Thank you bbgodfrey for your suggestion ....